# Remove fields from approval task

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, 2016, tasks

Is it possible to remove the fields "Status", "Solicitado por (Created by)", "Comentários consolidados (Consolidated comments)" and "Data de conclusão (due date)" with Sharepoint designer 2013? I can create fields "Analysis & Proposal" and so on but I can't remove these other fields. I can't use InfoPath because of licensing. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only option to modify the approval task form is either using InfoPath or using SharePoint 2013 workflow platform.

Comment: How can I remove it with Sharepoint 2013 workflow platform?